# Changing the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT value from Code

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I want to change the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT value from code while initializing the application. This is done with

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT", [newValue]);
```

and happens very early on startup of the application, prior to any calls to Use[XY].
If I check the value with `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")` throughout the lifetime of the application, it returns the desired value.

However, the Environment-Tag helper always uses the initial value which was set at the application's very startup (the old value).
While googling, I found a lot of posts on how to change the "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value from outside of the application, but none on how it is done from within the application.

The background of this question is, that we have the information about which stage the application runs, saved within the database and we want to use this information.

**Update**
It seems, that I have found the solution, will post it, if it is reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Asp.net Core initializes at the application’s start the `IWebHostEnvironment` implementing instance and registers it as a singleton. This interface has a read/write property `EnvironmentName`, which is then used throughout the application’s lifetime as the “environment” value.
Hence the solution was:

```
var webHostEnvironment = [ServiceCollection].GetRequiredService<IWebHostEnvironment>();
webHostEnvironment.EnvironmentName=[my value];
```

Important is surely, that the assignment is as early as possible, so that in the `Configure`-method of the application, it is already set to its target value.

I tested some scenarios and up to now, I haven’t found any problems.